# Vue rerender from data by async method

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an icon
that is displaying a `favorite`/`not favorite` state with a red or white heart.

`html`

```html
<img :src="favoriteStatus ? '/icons/liked@3x.png' : '/icons/like@3x.png'">
```

I call the api to get the status

```js
try {
  const res = await .......... ;
  if (res.cmd_data.code === 0) {
    this.favoriteStatus = res.cmd_data.msg;
    this.$forceUpdate();
  } else {
   ....
  }
} catch ......
```

`res.cmd_data.msg` is a Boolean.

My vue devtools are showing that `favoriteStatus` can be correctly changed (true or false).

But the heart icon not changing and `$forceUpdate()` is not working neither.

Comment: Check the final URL with your dev tools, what is the URL? Also, are you sure that the path is correct? Try to display it without any condition at first. Then, maybe try this ```<img :src="`url(${require('/icons/${favoriteStatus ? liked : like}@3x.png')})` ```.

Comment: the image is fine, I set true in data ( favoriteStatus: true ), the heart is changed to red.

Comment: no, just cmd_data: { code: 0, msg: false }

Comment: so it should be rendered  in my situation?

Comment: So, you do have a list of elements? How can you expect to have a local state per item if they do not carry the `favorite` state themselves? We will need more example of what you're trying to do here. Can you please make a [repro] on github or codesandbox?

Comment: it's working now, turns out, I should get the Initial value from api first, some reason I skipped. thanks you guys a lot

Comment: yes you did, should i click the vote arrow or..? sorry I am new

Comment: You can arrow up and click the tick below it to mark it as accepted yes please. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try this form

```html
<img :src="`url(${require('/icons/${favoriteStatus ? liked : like}@3x.png')})`
```

---

EDIT: At the end, it was just some lifecycle issue.
The OP fixed it by fiddling when fetching the API.